# Define a file path for saving uploaded file by users in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

Consider if we have a form which contains a field to upload a file by users like this :

```
class PoscastForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("title", "message", "channel", "file", "tag")
        model = models.Podcast

    def __ini__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if user is not None:
            self.fields["channel"].queryset = (
                models.Channel.objects.filter(
                    pk__in = user.channels.value_list('channel__pk')
                )
            )
```

And the Podcast model:

```
class Podcast(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="podcasts", 
on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, related_name="podcasts", 
null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
    tag = models.ForeignKey('podcasts.Tag', related_name="podcasts", 
null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, default='')
```

So when a user upload his attach file it will save in root directory of my project! How can I change the direction path?
The view for this form is look like this :

```
class CreatePodcast(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, 
generic.CreateView):
    fields = ("title", "message", "channel", "file", "tag")
    model = models.Podcast

   def form_valid(self, form):
       self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield), you can define the file path in the model definition

```
file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, default='', upload_to="your/path/")
```

Also if you define a [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT) then uploaded files will be sent to to the subdirectory of `MEDIA_ROOT` which is defined it `upload_to`. See the [storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage) documentation for more details.

Also you can define user wise upload directory. From documentation:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

# model defination
file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```